# Why is joining two vectors simply not working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

I have two vectors of MyObj structs.  MyObj is defined as follows:

```
struct MyObj
{
   float x, y;
   unsigned int data[8];
   unsigned int tmp[1];

   MyObj(const MyObj &m) 
   {
      x = m.x; y = m.y; 
      tmp[0] = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
      {
         data[i] = m.data[i];
      }
   }
};
```

I then have two vectors...

```
vector<MyObj> v1; 
vector<MyObj> v2;
// both get data eventually.

v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

v2 has 3535004 elements in my experiment.  v1 is similarly sized.  I've also tried building a new vector and just using .push_back to build it from both vectors.

Essentially, when I try to merge the two vectors I just get an error from visual studio saying "Debug error!  R6010, abort() has been called".  Very non-useful...

So my question is: what could be causing this error, and how can I solve it?  Thank you

Comment: Why do you have an array of one?

Comment: So the error doesn't happen when there are only 3535003 elements in each?

Comment: How much memory is on your system?  Try putting the contents of your main function in a try-catch block, catching std::exception and printing what().

Comment: When that error occurs and you _debug your program_, what is the current state of the program?  What is being executed when the error occurs?  What objects are in the source and target containers?  What is their state?  Does the state of those objects match the state you expect them to have?

Comment: r6010 referrers to an uncaught exception. Do you have any throws in your code?

Comment: @SethCarnegie testing purposes.  It grows throughout experiments.  To Beta nope... each vector gets filled on their own just fine. It's the merging process that is failing.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Debugging the program, both the vectors appear to have the correct data.  The source vectors are well filled.  I am just appending one to the other, essentially.  I also tried building a new empty vector and appending both to that, but still the same issue...

Comment: at this point you have to post a complete but minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Maybe memory manager is not able to reserve contiguous memory address range ~400MB, have you tried switching to deque?

Comment: Use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/capacity/), print out the results.  You can also try to [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) the space you'll need in advance in `v1`.

Comment: @MattPhillips capacity for v1: 3535004.  Capacity for v2: 3728868

Comment: @Ben: `std::vector::insert` throws an exception, which he isn't catching.

Comment: The exception generated by insert is "bad allocation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vtext.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct MyObj
{
   float x, y;
   unsigned int data[8];
   unsigned int tmp[1];

   MyObj() {}
   MyObj(const MyObj &m) 
   {
      x = m.x; y = m.y; 
      tmp[0] = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
      {
         data[i] = m.data[i];
      }
   }
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<MyObj> v1(3535004); 
    vector<MyObj> v2(3535004);
    // both get data eventually.

    v1.reserve(3535004 + 3535004);

    cout << v1.capacity() << endl;

    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());

    cout << "It worked" << endl;
}
```

> $ g++ vtest.cpp -o vtest
>
> $ ./vtest
>
> 7070008
>
> It worked

It worked with and without the `reserve` statement.  Either you are working on a very low memory system (mine has 4GB) or the error is in something you haven't shown us.

Edit: Following @MooingDuck's implied suggestion in his comment, if you still have problems replace the `insert` statement above with

```
try 
{
        v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
}
catch (exception& e)
{
   cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

and take it from there.  Also add `#include <exception>` at the top.

Comment: Just for more confirmation, the same code works for me in Visual Studio 2010 on a 4GB system.

Comment: Likewise, both with and without .reserve(). Ubuntu 4GB.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks.  The exception is "bad allocation".

Comment: @Jim So how much memory is on your system?  What else do you have running?

Comment: @MattPhillips 8GB of RAM, 200 GB of hard drive space.  Nothing substantial running

Comment: @Jim Well then I am pretty much out of tricks!  What compiler and version?  What OS?

Comment: There's no tricks here.  He's allocating too much contiguous memory, plain and simple.  Just because he has enough memory for the data, doesn't mean that the OS will be able to give him that much contiguously(which vector demands).  If he's going to manipulate data of this size, he needs to switch data structures.  deque was suggested, and it's a good suggestion.